# ASM Вставки iDIV

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, lazarus

//Pascal

```
NumX:=-40;
```

//Assm

```
MOV     EAX,NumX
MOV     ECX,4
IDIV    ECX
MOV     IntPart, EAX
```

Почему IntPart возвращает 1073741815?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что значение беззнаковое.
У вас в `EAX` помещается преобразованное в беззнаковое 4-байтное целое -40, что дает значение `FFFFFFD8`, или 4294967256 в десятичном виде.

Делим на 4, получаем `3FFFFFF6`, или 1073741814 в десятичном виде.

Вот как правильно должен выглядеть ваш код:

```
MOV     EAX,NumX
CDQ
MOV     ECX,4
IDIV    ECX
MOV     IntPart, EAX
```

Знаковое расширение `EAX` в `EDX:EAX` забыто...

Comment: А как сделать его знаковым?

Comment: Спасибо........

Comment: Я давно не работал с ассемблером, и дал в комментарии плохой совет. Хороший - в дополненном моем ответе: `CDQ`